# New version of if, what is it doing?

Tags: if-statement, scheme, conditional-statements

I am asked to interpret the output of a function with specific inputs but I don't understand how the function works. It is suppose to be a new version of if but to me it looks like it does nothing at all.

```
(define (if-2 a b c)
    (cond (a b)
    (else c)))
```

To me this just looks like it will always print b but I am not sure.

Comment: Why do you think it would always print `b`? Do you understand `cond`?

Comment: Yes I understand cond, and if for example I call (if-2 < 2 3) it evaluates teh expression (< 2) which is meaningless.

Comment: No, it evaluates the expression `<` and then it evaluates the expression `2`. This is, of course, also meaningless, but it's the exact same thing that would happen if you wrote `(if < 2 3)`.

Comment: `(if-2 < 2 3)` returns `2` - just like `(if < 2 3)` would (you could of course easily find this out yourself by typing `(if-2 < 2 3)` into the REPL ...).

Comment: I did and it returns 2 but I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are unfamiliar with the `cond` form.  It works like this:

```
(cond
  ((<predicate1> <args>) <actions>)
    ;^^-- this form evaluates to true or false. 
    ;  If true, we do <actions>, if not we move on to the next predicate.
  ((<predicate2> <args>) <actions>) ; We can have however many predicates we wish
  (else ;<-- else is always true.  This is our catch-all.
    <actions>))
```

Below is your code with some variables renamed.

```
(define (if-2 predicate arg1 arg2)
    (cond
      (predicate arg1)
      (else arg2)))
```

To figure out why it is always returning `arg1` for your tests, recall that Scheme sees everything as true except the explicit false symbol (usually `#f`) and the empty list `'()`.

So when you call `(if-2 > 2 3)` the cond form evaluates to this:

```
(cond
  (> 2)
  ;^---- `>` is not the empty list, so it evals to #t 
  (else 3))
```

Then since `cond` returns the first thing it finds to be associated with a true value you get 2 back.

To make `if-2` work as expected you need to call it differently, e.g. `(if-2 (> 3 2) 'yep! 'nope!)` will return `'yep!` since 3 is greater than 2.